# Aligning multiple equations in MathJax

Tags: mathjax

Is there a way to align multiple equations so the equators are underneath each other using MathJax?

```
For example:
 2x - 4 = 6
     2x = 10
      x = 5
```

Comment: I recommend that this question be migrated to [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use the `aligned` environment and the `&` symbol.

e.g.

```
$$\begin{aligned} 2x - 4 &= 6 \\ 2x &= 10 \\ x &= 5 \end{aligned}$$
```

I inserted `&` in front of `=` of each line so that the horizontal positions of `=`s will be the same for all the lines.

If you do not need such horizontal alignment, you can use `gathered` environment instead of `aligned` environment without `&`. It will horizontally center all the lines.

Comment: What about multiple alignment points? Is it possible with MathJax?

Comment: should this not be \begin{align}? e.g. https://marquis08.github.io/mathjax/minimalmistakes/align-equations-in-mathjax/

Comment: @Misrab In normal LaTeX, the `align` environment adds eq. numbering. The example equations do not have them.

Comment: This is because I chose to use the 'aligned' environment for consistency, although MathJax does not display equation numbering even in the 'align' environment.