# Aligning equations using Mathjax

Tags: mathjax

I'm trying to align equations underneath each other by the equator like this:

```
3x-1=-10
  3x=-9
   x=-3
```

But I'm not sure how. This is what I have:

```
`3x-1=-10 "<br>" 3x=-9 "<br>" x=-3`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aligning multiple equations in MathJax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977563/aligning-multiple-equations-in-mathjax)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Align equations with environment `align`:

```
\begin{align}
3x-1 &= -10 \\
  3x &= -9 \\
   x &= -3
\end{align}
```

[Live example in a sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29263)